# How to draw a rectangle with a background color in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, rectangles

Hi I want to have a rectangle like the below picture to fill the entire canvas with different sizes and at different position scatter through out the canvas. My solution environment is WPF C#

[image: rectangle with red background]

Could some one please guide me of how to do it? Till now what I have done is canvas_loaded

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(); 
rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
rect.Width = 100;
rect.Height = 100;
rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

But the problem here how will I position it to the different locaion of the canvas, the size and width I can provide at run time with different value but I need to position the rectangles (Square) at diffrent XY co-ordinates so that none of the rectangles or Squares overlapp each other.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Canvas.SetLeft(rect, <offset>) Canvas.SetRight(...), Canvas.SetTop(...), Canvas.SetBottom(...)
```

to position UIElement in the Canvas container.

Comment: Ok thanks, it answer my question of positioning the Rectangles in the Canvas, But how do I draw a rectangle like the picture, a with  a background shadow. Please

Comment: I think that canvas.SetRight or Canvas.SetBottom is not there in Canvas class.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setright.aspx its regarding SetRight for example.

Comment: how to add shadow you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831062/wpf-drop-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Use Random class to generate the xy co-ordinates

```
Random r=new Random();
r.Next(1,100);
```

Comment: this will definitely cause some rectangles to overlap